# Nuxt and Axios - javaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, axios, nuxt.js

I don't know what is going on with Nuxt and Axios, after the user session expire and the API returnsa a status 401, if I reload the page it get stuck and after a couple of minutes it return this error in console:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[85937:0x108000000]  4259490 ms: Mark-sweep 2025.8 (2050.9) -> 2025.0 (2050.9) MB, 1638.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.111, current mu = 0.006) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[85937:0x108000000]  4261994 ms: Mark-sweep 2025.9 (2050.9) -> 2025.0 (2051.2) MB, 2495.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.050, current mu = 0.004) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x100950919]
    1: StubFrame [pc: 0x1009523cb]
Security context: 0x0e33ea8c08d1 <JSObject>
    2: exec [0xe33ea8d49b1](this=0x0e3338818389 <JSRegExp <String[#10]: %[dfijoOs]>>,0x0e33ea8f5d61 <String[#51]: Cannot %s headers after they are sent to the client>)
    3: [Symbol.match] [0xe33ea8d4899](this=0x0e3338818389 <JSRegExp <String[#10]: %[dfijoOs]>>,0x0e33ea8f5d61 <String[#51]: Cannot %s headers after they are sen...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Writing Node.js report to file: report.20200403.123410.85937.0.001.json
Node.js report completed
 1: 0x100080c68 node::Abort() [/Users/aaa/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node]
 2: 0x100080dec node::errors::TryCatchScope::~TryCatchScope() [/Users/aaa/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node]
 3: 0x100185167 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/aaa/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node]
 4: 0x100185103 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/aaa/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node]
 5: 0x10030b2f5 v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*) [/Users/aaa/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node]
 6: 0x10030c9c4 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [/Users/aaa/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node]
 7: 0x100309837 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/Users/aaa/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node]
 8: 0x1003077fd v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/Users/aaa/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node]
 9: 0x100312fba v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLightRetry(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/Users/aaa/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node]
10: 0x100313041 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/Users/aaa/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node]
11: 0x1002e035b v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/Users/aaa/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node]
12: 0x100618718 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Users/aaa/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node]
13: 0x100950919 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_NoBuiltinExit [/Users/aaa/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node]
14: 0x1009523cb Builtins_SubString [/Users/aaa/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node]
```

The Node version I'm using is the **12.16.1**

The Axios Plugin file is this:

```
import https from 'https'

export default function({ $axios, redirect }) {
  const agent = new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  })

  // Axios default options
  $axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.apiBaseUrl
  $axios.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  $axios.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

  $axios.onRequest(config => {
    config.httpsAgent = agent
  })

  $axios.onError(({ response }) => {
    const statusCode = response.status
    const data = response.data
    switch (statusCode) {
      case 401:
        redirect('/session-expired')
        break
      case 404:
        let path = '/404'
        redirect(path)
        break
      case 500:
        return this.$nuxt.error({ statusCode })
      default:
        return false
    }
  })
}
```

The `@nuxt/axios` version is the latest: 5.9.7.

I think the issue is in the `onError` method because as soon as I comment it out I can run the application... Why does it happen?

Comment: What is your nuxt version?

Comment: Nuxt version is: 2.11.0

Answer (score 5):

Nuxt's dev mode appears to have a long history of having memory leaks. Try adding `standalone: true` to the `build` object in your `nuxt.config`, so it might look something like this:

```js
export default {
  build: {
    standalone: true,
 }
}
```

If that doesn't help you, maybe some of these github issues and pull requests can: [#6478](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6478) [#5452](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/5452) [#286](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/issues/286) [#685](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/issues/286)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already use `standalone: true`... :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too but I found a very obvious answer.

Please, check name of your components. In my case I had 2 components which have the same name.

```
export default {
   name: "Test"
}
```

With this I wasn't able to run my app and I had same error as you. Maybe that will help someone

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was Axios, In Nuxt Config,

```js
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_ENDPOINT_URL,
    // Proxy: true,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `bearer ${process.env.STRAPI_TOKEN}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  },
```

The baseURL wasn't pointing to anything because I haven't added it to my `.env` file.

You can check that or add a fallback incase.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this is and after some research I found it was because I was had not set the Axios baseURL. My setup was attempting to set the axios baseURL dynamically at runtime by grabbing the subdomain from a wildcard setup (*.example.com).

The problem is that in a SSR application, requests will be made to your backend before rendering the application and this often happens on reload.

You'd have to write a plugin that ensures that the axios baseURL is present on the server and on the client.